# Comparing equal strings returns False?

Tags: python, string, comparison

So I'm making a basic makeshift login validate thing with just a basic text file to "pretend" and what should return True is not. The username check works but not the password check

```
@staticmethod
def validate_login(filename,username,password):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        i = [i for i, char in enumerate(line) if char == '|']
        print username == line[i[0] + 2:i[1]-1]
        print password == line[i[1] + 2:]
        print password
        print line[i[1] + 2:]
        if username == line[i[0] + 2:i[1]-1] and password == line[i[1] + 2:]:
            file.close()
            print "Login Successful."
            return True

    file.close()
    print "Failed to login. Invalid username or password."
    return False
```

This is the output result. The password matches exactly with the text file yet returns false. The username returns true.What exactly is the issue?? It is driving me insane.

```
True <--- username matched correctly returns true
False <---passwords apparently don't match, returns false.
DopeFiend97 <--password
DopeFiend97
```

Comment: You likely have a newline `\n` in your password comparison. You will need to `strip()` it off. Any reason not to use `split`, e.g. `u, p = line.strip().split('|'); if username == u and password == p): ...`

Comment: Fixed it, had to use line.strip()

Answer (score 1):

Had to use .strip() function to remove unforeseen characters at the end of the line.