# Comparing a string with the one returned from `.readlines()` always gives False

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, readlines

It seems that right now my if-statements don't register that another variable is equal to one stated. I have even printed the variable stored that the guess is to check-against, and both the guess and variable stored should be equal to each other.

I have tried making it case-sensitive, and without. I have tried displaying the variable to then type it out exactly and it just won't work.

```
import random
from random import randint

loop = 0
score = 0


f = open("songs.txt", "r")
line_number = randint(0,3)
lines = f.readlines()
songname = lines[line_number]

firstletters = songname.split()
letters = [firstletters[0] for firstletters in firstletters]
print(" ".join(letters))

f.close()

f = open("artists.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
artistname = lines[line_number]

print("The first letter of each word in the title of the song is: " + "".join(letters))
print("The artist of the above song is: " + artistname)

print(songname)

answer = songname

guess = input("What is your guess? ")

if guess.lower()==answer:
  score = score + 3
  print("Correct! You have earned three points, and now have a total of:",score, "points!")

else:
  print("Incorrect! You have one more chance to guess it correctly!")
  guesstwo = input("What is your second guess? ")

  if guesstwo.lower()==answer:
    score = score + 1
    print("Correct! You have earned one point, and now have a total of:",score, "points!")

  else:
    print("Incorrect! Unfortunately you have guessed incorrectly twice- therefore the game has now ended. You had a total of:",score,"points!")
```

If the "guess" variable equals the `songname` variable, then it should display the `"Correct! You have earned three points, and now have a total of:",score, "points!"` message, although right now it always displays the `Song is Incorrect` message.

The songs stored in the file are:

```
Africa
Redding
Follow
Fleekes
```

Comment: Can you print guess and answer just to double check please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing equal strings returns False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906598/comparing-equal-strings-returns-false)

Comment: Rather than reading the entire line into memory, use `islice` to get the desired line directly from the iterable (without reading more than you really need to). For example, `songname = next(islice(f, linenumber, None)).strip()`. You still need to read each line until you get the one you want, but each unwanted line is discarded as it is read, rather than keeping it in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by converting also answer to lowercases.

```
if guess.lower() == answer.lower():
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't make a difference- the suggestion from Patrick Haugh seemed to have corrected it. I do appreciate your message back though.

Comment: @BenHams Why did you accept this answer, and not the one from Patrick?

Answer (score 1):

`readlines` doesn't strip the newlines off the end of each line.  If you `print(repr(songname))`, you'll see that it has a `\n` on the end.  You can fix that by calling `strip` yourself:

```
songname = lines[line_number].strip()
```